# VS2017 RC - The following error occurred when trying to configure IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, iis-express

Installed VS2017 RC - Started New Project ASP.NET Core Web Aplication(.Net CORE), selected Individual User Accounts as Authentication type. Try to run code generated with no changes and got the following error: Error occurred when trying to configure IIS Express for project... Error: ../.vs/config/applicationhost.config Error: cannot write configuration file

Looked at that file and it appears that it should have been writable.

FYI using VS2015 Update 3 everything builds and runs as expected including IIS Express.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having this issue, but only after the recent updated to Visual Studio 2017 RC (12/12/16).

I searched for a good hour and really didn't find anything, so I simply downloaded the latest IIS Express (v10) and it seems to have corrected the issues for 2017, but also for 2015 that started after the update as well.

[IIS Express Download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48264)

Comment: I just tried this and the error changed to "The AspNetCoreModule which is required to host .NET Core projects in IIS does not appear to be installed"

Comment: @MartínColl I have the same problem as you did. Any solution?

Comment: Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51756931/3341032), it worked for me

Answer (score 16):

I have encountered the same issue but deleting .vs folder worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

EFS (Encryption File System) is known to cause file access problems. Ensure that EFS is turned off in your project directory.

More information:
https://blog.danielsmon.com/2017/04/03/cant-write-to-applicationhost-config/