# Visual Studio Website is throwing the error "You do not have permission to access the IIS configuration file"

Tags: c#, iis

When opening my Visual Studio web application while I'm on the organizations network I do not receive this error.  It only occurs when I'm disconnected from the network.

The error is as follows:
"Creation of the virtual directory http://localhost:" ...  "failed with the error: You do not have permission to access the IIS configuration file.  Opening and creating web sites in IIS requires running Visual Studio under an Administrator account."

I am using an ID with administrator privilege's and I've also tried using the Administrator ID.  I've started Visual Studio as an administrator.  The PC itself has IIS loaded.  The only thing I can think of is that there is an underlying communication with the organizations IIS server but I can't find it in the Web.Config file and I have no connectivity to the organizations IIS server in the scripts and .aspx files I've developed.  Any Ideas?

I've checked online and I don't see anybody posting the scenario I'm having causing this error.

Comment: Ask administrators of your organization to open a support case with Microsoft for this issue please. There are quite a few causes of such an ambiguous error message, so you shouldn't expect a place like here can give you the exact answer.

Comment: This is a very generic error, there is no specific cause for this, here is the same error you can use as reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233319/you-do-not-have-permission-to-access-the-iis-configuration-file-web-app-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56233319/you-do-not-have-permission-to-access-the-iis-configuration-file-web-app-error), I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com, microsoft engineers will help find the root cause.